# How to eliminate a potential race condition between two script onload handlers

Tags: javascript, if-statement, promise, onload, race-condition

I forked some code that was relying on two timers instead of a script's `onload` handler.  My first attempt eliminated one of the handlers, and made the other more robust by using `setInterval`, and shortened the time as well as it ran after one interval:

```
    isRendered: false,
    loadScript: function(src) {
        var s = document.createElement('script');
        var interval;

        s.type = 'text/javascript';
        s.async = true;
        s.src = src;
        s.onload = (function() {
            if (src === prettifyJs) {
                interval = setInterval(function() {
                    if (upstaged.isRendered) {
                        clearInterval(interval);
                        // Highlight any code out there
                        prettyPrint();
                    }
                }, 25);
            }
            if (src === showdownJs) {
                upstaged.render(upstaged.markdownContent);
                upstaged.isRendered = true;
                upstaged.afterRender();                 
            }
        });

        var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
    },
```

I've since devised a way to eliminate the second timer but it relies on a flag or another, function, value, and I'm concerned there could be a slim chance of a race condition if the condition within the prettifyJs handler executes neither the `if` nor `else` because `upstaged.isRendered` gets updated by showdown's handler between the two.  Should I be concerned and go back to the setInterval way which won't be subject to a race condition?  Or is there another way such as through using promises (not my forte).  I've used a countdown before before when waiting for several Ajax calls to return, but this seems like the "temporal dependence" between the two onload scripts would still exist.

```
    isRendered: false,
    onPrettifyJsLoaded: function() {},
    loadScript: function(src) {
        var s = document.createElement('script');
        var interval;

        s.type = 'text/javascript';
        s.async = true;
        s.src = src;
        s.onload = (function() {
            if (src === prettifyJs) {
                if (upstaged.isRendered)  {
                    prettyPrint();
                }
                else {
                    upstaged.onPrettifyJsLoaded = function() {prettyPrint()};
                }
            }
            if (src === showdownJs) {
                upstaged.render(upstaged.markdownContent);
                upstaged.isRendered = true;
                upstaged.onPrettifyJsLoaded();
                upstaged.afterRender();                 
            }
        });

        var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
    },
```

Comment: Why `setInterval()` instead of using the `defer` keyword to make sure the script runs only after the full DOM is available?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans This has nothing to do with the DOM, is that the only usage for `defer`?  I'm not so familar with that anyway, and the `setInterval` "worked".  I'm trying to get away from the timer approach altogether, see the second code block please.

Answer (score 0):

I solved similar task via Promises like:

```
var loadScriptDependence = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let scr = document.createElement('script');
        scr.type = "text/javascript";
        scr.async = true;
        scr.src = `/script/dependence.js`;
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(scr);
        scr.onload = (() => resolve(true));
        scr.onerror = () => reject(Error('Error loading dependence.'));
    });

var loadDependedScript = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let scr = document.createElement('script');
        scr.type = "text/javascript";
        scr.async = true;
        scr.src = `/script/depended.js`;
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(scr);
        scr.onload = (() => resolve(true));
        scr.onerror = () => reject(Error('Error loading depended.'));
    });

loadScriptDependence
  .then(() => loadDependedScript)
  .then(() => doSomething())
  .catch((err) => console.error('Error occured'))
```

Comment: I will try but it might not be for a couple of days.  Thanks for your interest and I will let you know how it goes.  As I said, promises are not my strong point :(  Could be a good learning opportunity.